# How to concisely split string into 3 words?

Tags: string, rust, idioms

*Disclaimer 1: I am a complete beginner in Rust.*

*Disclaimer 2: this is a question mostly about codestyle. Call it "idiomatic" :)*

I have a `String`. It should contain 3 words delimited by a space, and I need these 3 words.
My question is: how to do it ***concisely***?

Variant 1: the simplest

```rust
let line: String = // ...
let line_split = line.split(" ").collect::<Vec<&str>>();
let word1 = line_split[0];
let word2 = line_split[1];
let word3 = line_split[2];
// or
let line_split = line.split(" ");
let word1 = line_split.next().unwrap();
let word2 = line_split.next().unwrap();
let word3 = line_split.next().unwrap();
```

This is too long, repetitive, and error-prone.

Variant 2: doesn't compile

```rust
let line: String = // ...
let [word1, word2, word3] = line.split(" ").collect::<Vec<&str>>()[..];
```

This is the syntax that I am looking for, but Rust compiler forces me to check all patterns `[], [_], ...`

Variant 2.1: compiles

```rust
let line: String = // ...
if let [word1, word2, word3] = line.split(" ").collect::<Vec<&str>>()[..] {
    // ...
} else {
    panic!("line doesn't have exactly 3 words");
}
```

This introduces an extra scope. If I do such `if let` several times (which I need to), the scope will get too nested for no reason.

Variant 2.2: hiding extra scopes

```rust
fn split_3(line: &str, pattern: &str) -> (&str, &str, &str) {
    if let [word1, word2, word3] = line.split(pattern).collect::<Vec<&str>>()[..] {
        return (word1, word2, word3);
    } else {
        panic!("line doesn't have exactly 3 words");
    }
}
```

Now the problem is to split the line into 2 words (which I need to as well), I have to declare `fn split_2(...)` which is basically copypaste. And I can't pass 3 or 2 as a parameter, because the whole point is to have the tuple size at compile-time.

So, is there any better solution? If not, which one of these I should use?

Comment: Do you really want to panic when there are not exactly three words on a line? This soudns like suboptimal error handling. I'm asking because taking proper error handling into account will change what you (or anyone) might consider the optimnal solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```rust
fn main() {
    let line: String = String::from("ab cd ef");

    let [word1, word2, word3]: [&str; 3] =
        line.split(" ").collect::<Vec<&str>>().try_into().unwrap();

    println!("{}", word1);
    println!("{}", word2);
    println!("{}", word3);
}
```

Although this contains the allocation of a new vector.

I'd argue that this is already the most ideal solution:

```rust
let line_split = line.split(" ");
let word1 = line_split.next().unwrap();
let word2 = line_split.next().unwrap();
let word3 = line_split.next().unwrap();
```

I am unsure why you think this is error prone, repetitive, or too long. In my opinion, this is exactly what you want.

---

Some alternatives:

```rust
fn split_twice<'a>(s: &'a str, delim: &str) -> Option<(&'a str, &'a str, &'a str)> {
    let (s1, s) = s.split_once(delim)?;
    let (s2, s3) = s.split_once(delim)?;
    Some((s1, s2, s3))
}

fn main() {
    let line: String = String::from("ab cd ef");

    let (word1, word2, word3) = split_twice(&line, " ").unwrap();

    println!("{}", word1);
    println!("{}", word2);
    println!("{}", word3);
}
```

Very good error handling, but limited to a fixed number of repeats.

Also good, because no code duplication:

```rust
fn main() {
    let line: String = String::from("ab cd ef");

    let mut line_split = line.split(" ");
    let [word1, word2, word3] = [(); 3].map(|()| line_split.next().unwrap());
}
```

Or the improved version (thanks @PitaJ):

```rust
fn main() {
    let line: String = String::from("ab cd ef");

    let mut line_split = line.split(" ");
    let [word1, word2, word3] = std::array::from_fn(|_| line_split.next().unwrap());
}
```

Or if you don't like the fact that there is now the `line_split` variable, then move it to a local scope:

```rust
fn main() {
    let line: String = String::from("ab cd ef");

    let [word1, word2, word3] = std::array::from_fn({
        let mut line_split = line.split(" ");
        move |_| line_split.next().unwrap()
    });
}
```

Comment: One thing I might add is to use `splitn` instead of just split, so that you always know exactly how many strings you'll have, and hopefully the compiler can optimize some panics away.

Comment: What I dislike about code with `line_split.next().unwrap()` is: a) same line repeats several times b) if I accidentally reorder lines, I get a logical error c) it is a lot longer than other solutions d) it introduces a redundant variable `line_split`

Comment: a) Same line repeating several times is not a bad thing per se. But I added an example with `[(); 3].map()` that avoids that duplication. b) If you accidentally reorder lines, you always get logical errors. That's true for all code, not just that specific one. c) length is not a bad thing, if it provides readability. d) redundant variables are neither slow nor bad coding style. Intermediate variables are very important for readability. Always make your intermediate steps clear, don't put too many things in the same line.

Comment: I think you can use `std::array::from_fn` instead of your map code there.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using the `itertools` crate which makes this (and many other things) quite convenient, in this particular case with `collect_tuple`:

```rust
use itertools::Itertools;

fn main() {
    let s = "foo bar baz";
    let (a, b, c) = s.split(" ").collect_tuple().unwrap();
    println!("{a} {b} {c}");
}
```